# Can an Indian passport holder travel to the UAE from India with 4-month passport validity?

Tags: indian-citizens, airlines, passport-renewals, visa-expiration, valid

I have an Indian passport with 4 months validity. I have to travel from India to the UAE.  I have a short-term visa to the UAE. Can I travel with 4 months validity?